# Por que no consigo que me de la información en pantalla

Tags: javascript

No entiendo por que no me da el resultado, si pongo un "console.log()" si pero si no, no me sale y no doy con click
He estado probando y no se si necesito meter la función en una variable o si es que no le estoy dando la orden correcta

```js
document.querySelector("#boton1").addEventListener('click', () => {
  var cadena = document.querySelector('#frase').value;
    
  function contarNum() {
    ncad=cadena.split(' ').filter(String).join('').split(''); //convertir la cadena en array de caracteres eliminando los espacios
    nnum=ncad.filter(num => num >= 0 && num <= 9);            //para obtener los numeros solo basta con esta comparacion  
    
    return {
      numeros: nnum.length,                        //total de numeros
      espacios: cadena.split(' ').length-1,        //total de espacios
      otroscaracteres: ncad.length-nnum.length     //el numero de letras es el total de caracteres - el de numeros
    };
  }
  
  document.querySelector('#resultado').innerHTML = contarNum();
})
```

```html
<input id="frase" cols="30" rows="10">
<button id="boton1">
calcular
</button>
<output id="resultado"></output>
```

Comment: He añadido `})` al final del código para que no de error de sintaxis y el código se ejecute, deberías revisar esos detalles si quieres crear un [mcve]. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y completar el [tour] del sitio

Comment: no da error de sintaxis, }) están bien puestos como mucho me ha podido faltar el ; tras ellos puesto que son necesarios para cerrar la función principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando quieres añadir **texto** en un documento HTML, mediante la modificación de la propiedad `innerHTML` has de pasarle algo que sea ... bueno, **texto** (un string). Cuando intentas usar un objeto que no es un `String`, muchas funciones de Javascript llaman al método `Object.toString()` para obtener el valor que necesitan. Lamentablemente, el método `toString()` que hay por defecto simplemente escribe [object Object]. Podrías hacer algo como:

```js
document.querySelector("#boton1").addEventListener('click', () => {
  var cadena = document.querySelector('#frase').value;
    
  function contarNum() {
    const words = cadena.split(' ')
    const chars = words.join('').split(''); // convertir la cadena en array de caracteres eliminando los espacios
    const digits = chars.filter(num => num >= 0 && num <= 9); // para obtener los numeros solo basta con esta comparacion  
    
    return `
    <ul>
      <li>Números : ${digits.length}</li>
      <li>Espacios : ${words.length - 1}</li>
      <li>Otros carácteres : ${chars.length - digits.length}</li>
    </ul>`
  }
  document.querySelector('#resultado').innerHTML = contarNum();
})
```

```html
<input id="frase" cols="30" rows="10">
<button id="boton1">
calcular
</button>
<output id="resultado"></output>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo